# Save custom field value to variable for conditional - why is this not working?

Tags: php, custom-field

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, and have a select field labeled "type". I'm trying to save the value of the field to a variable for use in an if/else statement, and while the following works:

```
if(get_field('type') == 'document') {
    echo 'Document type';
}
```

... the following does not, when trying to compare against the value saved in a variable instead:

```
$type = get_field('type');

if ($type == 'document') {
    echo 'Document type';
}
```

What is happening here? Thanks for any insight here!

Comment: What is thie custom field attached to?

Comment: @belinus it is a `select` field type in Advanced Custom Fields; am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: This will depend on a couple things.  Are you allowing multiple options?  Are you returning value, label, or both( array)?

Comment: @rudtek I'm not allowing multiple options, allowing 'null' and interestingly I'm not seeing a return format; I'm using the free version and can't seem to find what the default return format is from the docs?

Comment: okay just do echo $type;  what do you get?

Comment: Use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on the $type variable to see what working with.

Answer (score 1):

So as described in the docs, the `get_field` function will try to get the `post id` that your field is associated. If he can't it will return nothing, so you have to pass the `post id` yourself, like the example below that I got in the docs:

```
$post_id = false; // current post
$post_id = 1; // post ID = 1
$post_id = "user_2"; // user ID = 2
$post_id = "category_3"; // category term ID = 3
$post_id = "event_4"; // event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4
$post_id = "option"; // options page
$post_id = "options"; // same as above

$value = get_field( 'my_field', $post_id );
```

To learn more about see in the [Docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).